# Will Java record classes be allocated on the stack?

Tags: java, memory

```
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for(var i=0; ; i++) {
      test(i);
    }
  }

  public static void test(int i) throws Exception{
   var p = new Point(1,2);

   if(i > 100_000) {
    Thread.currentThread().join();
   }
 }
}
record Point(int x, int y) {}
```

If I new a Point object, will this object be allocated on the stack?

JDK version `java version "18.0.2" Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit` 
JVM args `java -Xcomp -XX:-UseCompressedOops -XX:-UseCompressedClassPointers Hello.java` 
I use `jhsdb` to see if the point object is still allocated in the heap. So I have a question, will simple objects be allocated on the stack?

Now I have modified the code, will this Record class trigger the allocation on the stack?

Comment: Why are you joining on the current thread?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be created on the stack?

Comment: If you want to have objects that are allocated on the stack, you'll need to wait for Project Valhalla's [Primitive Classes](https://openjdk.org/jeps/401).

Comment: What does 'use scalar replacement on the stack' mean?

Comment: It is not the case that record classes are always allocated on the stack, and record classes are not [value classes](https://openjdk.org/jeps/8277163). It's up to the JVM / JIT to decide to allocate objects on the stack. One of the tricks it does is [escape analysis](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/escape-analysis-in-the-hotspot-jit-compiler), which means that it may allocate an object on the stack if possible.

Comment: @dan1st - that is a way to deadlock the main thread so that the JVM doesn't exit.

Answer (score 2):

Pulling together the various comments into an answer ...

> Will Java record classes be allocated on the stack?

In general: No.  Java `record` classes are first class.  They have reference-based identity and record values are not limited by the language to the scope in which they were allocated.  Therefore, in general they **cannot** be allocated on the stack.

The JIT compiler in a current generation HotSpot JVM can perform a form of optimization called *escape analysis* ... to determine if objects allocated in a method are able to "escape".  This involves analysis of the method that allocated the object and any other methods that it passes the object to.  If an object can be shown to never escape, the JIT compiler can arrange that it is not allocated in the heap.  For more details see:

- [Escape Analysis in the HotSpot JIT Compiler](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/escape-analysis-in-the-hotspot-jit-compiler)

Note that escape analysis applies to `record` classes and other (regular) Java classes.  It depends on how the objects are used, and whether the JIT compiler can establish the preconditions exist.  Things that could inhibit the optimization include:

- assigning the `record` object reference to the field of some other object or array
- returning the `record` object from the method that created it,
- debugging the JVM.

Note that escape analysis only happens when the method that allocates the `record` object is JIT compiled.  In your example, the `main` method code will not be run enough times to trigger JIT compilation.

---

@Jesper mentions *Value Objects* as proposed by [this draft JEP](https://openjdk.org/jeps/8277163).  This is a new kind of class for which would have value-based identity semantics.  The `==` operator would compare them by comparing the objects' fields rather than their references.  These *could* be optimized to allocate the values on the stack or to embed them in other objects; e.g. on the heap.

So Value Objects would be a good way to get (probably) stack-allocated objects.

However:

- This is just a draft proposal.  It doesn't have JEP status yet.
- A JVM *could* just allocate value objects as normal objects.  Indeed the proposal still describes value classes as reference types.
- Java `record` classes are not value classes anyway.  In the proposal, a value class is flagged with the keyword `value`, and this may be applied to `record` classes.  It is NOT proposed to retrospectively make *all* `record` classes value classes: that would be a breaking change.

---

@dan1st mentions *Primitive Classes* as described in [JEP 401](https://openjdk.org/jeps/401).  These differ from Value Objects in that the are NOT reference types at all.  That means that they cannot be compared with `null`.  However there will be *conversions* to translate between (corresponding) Primitive class and Value class objects.

---

It should be noted that these features are not yet present in or (publicly) scheduled for any upcoming mainstream Java release.   And they could change in the meantime.

Comment: Please see if the latest code will trigger allocation on the stack?

Comment: I can't tell you if it will.  It will depend on the optimizer.

Comment: The only way to be sure is to turn on the JVM flags for dumping the native code emitted by the JIT compiler, then unpick the native code.  And the answer will most likely depend on your JVM version.